# eModal load javascript in bootstrap 3 but not working in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using [eModal](https://github.com/saribe/eModal) plugin in my codeigniter project to show modal with ajax
the problem is when the modal is showing the Javascript/jQuery inside is not loaded
the javascript loaded only if i reopen the modal for second time,
i know i can put the javascript code on the ajax callback but i did not intended to do that
this code previously is working in bootstrap 3.3.7 but does not work in bootstrap v4.3.1

show modal function :

```
    eModal.ajax({
        title: 'Edit Variant',
        url: "localhost/kb_admin/product/input_variant"
    });
```

modal views (inside modal)

```js
alert('script loaded');
$('#form-input-variant').submit(function(){
    alert('form submitted');
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<table class="table">
        <form autocomplete="off" id="form-input-variant" method="post">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Color</th>
                    <td class="text-left">: WHITE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Size</th>
                    <td class="text-left">: L</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Price</th>
                    <td class="text-left">
                        <input id="price_variant" name="price_variant" type="text" class="number-format form-control" maxlength="8" placeholder="Enter Price" value="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="row" colspan="2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-style="expand-right"> Save </button>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </form>
    </table>
```

jquery: v3.31
bootsrap: v4.3.1
eModal: v1.2.67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test it on fiddle.
https://unpkg.com/emodal@1.2.69/dist/eModal.min.js
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
and jquery 3.3.1

```
<table class="table">
...your html
</table>
```

JavaScript

```js
alert('script loaded');
 $('#form-input-variant').on('submit', function(e){
   alert('form submitted');
    e.preventDefault();
});

var options = {
        # For testing
        message: $(".table"),
        # You should use
        url: "localhost/kb_admin/product/input_variant",
        title: 'Edit Variant',
        size: 'lg',
        subtitle: 'smaller text header',
        useBin: true
    };

eModal.alert(options);
```

Just look at the documentation: http://saribe.github.io/eModal/

Comment: i already read the documentation, unfortunately in this case I can't use fiddle because the modal require to load separated view using ajax

Comment: Did you test it with the JavaScript I posted? I used your url. If your modal form is in the DOM you can use message: $(".table").

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't include the useBin options before, now it's working fine, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually manage to find solution myself by changing eModal.js

line 375

from

```
function ok(html) {
            $modal
                .find('.' + MODAL_BODY)
                .html(data.success ? data.success(html) : html);

            return dfd.resolve($modal);
        }
```

to

```
function ok(html) {
            $modal
                .find('.' + MODAL_BODY)
                .empty()
                .append(data.success ? data.success(html) : html);

            return dfd.resolve($modal);
        }
```

i dunno how, but the javascript in the modal loaded properly now